# osmdroid-packager Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

This is mostly a java question, and likely something I'm overlooking.

I've been trying to use osmdroid-packager (http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/wiki/HowToUsePackager) to package map tiles for my android app, on Ubuntu Linux.  I've been following the instructions on the site above, and have run into some issues.

I have in my current directory, osmdroid-android-3.0.8.jar, osmdroid-packager-3.0.8.jar, and slf4j-android-1.6.1-RCq.jar.  I've setting the classpath, and attempting to run using the commands below gives me the error

> 'Could not find or load main class
>   org.osmdroid.mtp.OSMMapTilePackager'

I've also tried different variations of setting the classpath (setting classpath, CLASSPATH, to the jars, to the current directory, with -classpath) with the same result.  The best I can come up with is that the class is not in the jar.

The commands I tried from the website above were:

```
set classpath='osmdroid-android-3.0.8.jar;osmdroid-packager-3.0.8.jar;slf4j-android-1.6.1-RC1.jar;sqlitejdbc-v056.jar'


java org.osmdroid.mtp.OSMMapTilePackager -u http://tile.openstreetmap.org/%d/%d/%d.png -t Mapnik -d haarlem.zip -zmax 18 -n 52.4244 -s 52.3388 -e 4.6746 -w 4.594

java -cp . org.osmdroid.mtp.OSMMapTilePackager
```

also gives the same error.

I haven't downloaded a copy of sqlitejdbc yet, but I'm pretty sure that's not the issue.

Comment: Try to run that thing as an administrator. It helps.

Answer (score -1):

Use a 3.0.3 version to osmdroid-packager , osmdroid-packager for example

Use the same versions od libriries to this prompt command

set classpath=osmdroid-android-3.0.3.jar;osmdroid-packager-3.0.3.jar;slf4j-android-1.5.8.jar;sqlitejdbc-v056.jar
java org.andnav2.osm.mtp.OSMMapTilePackager -u http://tile.openstreetmap.org/%d/%d/%d.png -t Mapnik -d haarlem.zip -zmax 18 -n 52.4244 -s 52.3388 -e 4.6746 -w 4.5949